# Error in dptm(pts, myMeans, wgts, ppDim, kkMean, nn) : could not find function "dptm"

Tags: r

I'm trying to classify a mixed type dataset using Kamila algorithm. The implementation seems easy, I have this one. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7oDs.png).
However, when i run this code this error appears: Error in dptm(pts, myMeans, wgts, ppDim, kkMean, nn) :
could not find function "dptm"
Has someone ever experienced something like that?